# How can I import value into cssstyle.php file?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, variables

so I'm creating this wordpress theme and I ran into a php related problem (I think).

I created an options panel for users, where they can determine the main theme color.
For test I put the value #008A00 in there.

Now I've got my CSS in PHP file, so I can use variables - and it is working pretty neat as long as I use values inside of the file only.

So the following code works:

```
<?php

header('Content-type:text/css');
$color = '#008A00';
?>

#logo .rect {
display:inline-block;
height:45px;
width:15px;
background: <?php echo $color ?>;
margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

The problem starts when I try to call the value set by  user like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-type:text/css');
$color = get_option('shoboto_maincolor');
?>
```

If I put it like this (I also tried $color = print get_option('shoboto_maincolor'); and $color = echo get_option('shoboto_maincolor');), not only does the color dissapear, but also all the other styling, even if not variable-dependent.

My first thoughts were that I made a mistake in options or in other places, so to test that I put the code:

```
<?php print get_option('shoboto_maincolor'); ?>
```

in footer.php and it displayed the value #008A00 without any problems.

Could the problem be that cssstyle.php is placed within a folder and not in the same folder as shoboto-options.php, where the functions grab the value from user? Or am I doing something else wrong? Please advise.

Comment: you are probably getting a fatal error since the wordpress framework is not included in your css php script. And without the framework php doesnt know what `get_option` is and errors out, check your error log you should see an error in there about get_option not being a function.

Comment: Include that CSS file too

Comment: How do I do that? Like this?

<?php

header('Content-type:text/css');
define( 'TEMPPATH', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'));
define( 'OPT', TEMPLATEPATH . "/options");
require_once OPT . "/shoboto-options.php";

$color = get_option('shoboto_maincolor');
?>

Comment: Pro answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54583/12615

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by checking what is coming into the $color variable to ensure it is what you expect.

For example

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/css');
$color = get_option('shoboto_maincolor');

if (!$color==='#008A00')
{
  // DO SOMETHING - Color is NOT what was expected
}
?>
```

Run the code and pick that specific color, I'd expect you'll find it is not the correct variable contents
I'm not familiar with Wordpress so unsure how to act on the bad info within the IF statement

Comment: I tried something like this, same result. There must be something going on with errors since the styling stops being applied at all, not only color.

`<?php
header('Content-type:text/css');
$color = get_option('shoboto_maincolor');

if (!$color=='#008A00')
{
  $color = '#f26522';
}
?>`

Comment: I can see why styling might get messed up by some of your other changes [ $color = print get_option('shoboto_maincolor'); and $color = echo get_option('shoboto_maincolor');) ]
BUT - if it works as you say with the specific assignment of $color = '#008A00' in the php file then the only issue is what is in that variable $color.  I would not deviate far from this to find the problem. It's easy to get confused.

Comment: another possibility, perhaps $color is not the best name to use, it may be getting overwritten elsewhere when you call the option('shoboto_maincolor')

Try using a more unique/distinct variable name such as $xyz_onceoff_color     unlikely this would be used elsewhere